# Where can I find mecha schematics?

Tags: resources

I am writing a short story and need the schematics of the Escaflowne or any other mecha robot to add details to my story. Transformers schematics work too. Particularly, the torso part of the rider and the overall robot itself. I know Transformers don't have riders, but you get the jist.
All the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google search led me to [this page](http://www.macross2.net/m3/m3.html), where you can find a full list of mechas from the [Macross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macross) franchise (a quick browse through some pages there showed me that not all mecha have schematics there). For example, [this page](http://www.macross2.net/m3/sdfmacross/destroid-spartan.htm) in particular has all the details for the "Centinental/Kransmann MBR-07-Mk II Spartan Main Battle Robot", along with some perspectives and schematics.
[image: Conceptual schematics] [image: Schematics]

[Searching Google for "anime mecha schematics"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1366&bih=629&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=anime+mecha+schematics&oq=anime+mecha+schematics&gs_l=img.3...0.0.0.460420.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..56.img..0.0.0.afD_v5kWQc0) also shows a lot of results (many of them are from the website referred above):

[image: Google images results]

Some of them even seem to be rather detailed, like this one (despite its small size):
[image: One of the images from Google images search results]

You can always follow the images to their source, and possibly find some more results that may interest you.

I also found [this other site](http://www.mahq.net/) where you can find some other drawings of mecha from some series, including [Gundam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gundam). In this one, p.e., you can find schematics for the cockpit (in the bottom):
[image: Cockpit for ZGMF-X09A Justice Gundam]

I also found [this forum](http://www.mechatalk.net/), where you may find something if you have some time and patience (I didn't). For instance, in [this thread](http://www.mechatalk.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=351&start=280) I found [this drawing](http://www.gearsonline.net/series/gunbuster/gunbuster/bw62.jpg) from [Gunbuster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunbuster).

For Escaflowne in particular, however, I was not able to find anything.

Comment: Gee thanks that is probably all I need at this time. Also, I have to ask, can you add pictures here via the app? I couldn't find any options to do so.

Comment: And how do these numbers below our names work, I see you have a lot of them. In a second look I see that they represent gold, silver and bronze something. What else is there to it? Amd what about the numbers in bold?

Comment: @Aviraj_bhaiya I don't think you can add images from the app. Also, the large number by the name is [reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/192960) and the smaller numbers are [badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/192960). (These topics are covered in the FAQ also.)

Answer (score 3):

Search for the phrase「設定資料」in kanji and "*settei*" in romaji instead of "schematics" and you will find more.  "*Settei*" means the reference materials for animators so that when each ones draws the animation cels, they are consistent with the design. Search for 「設定資料」plus the name of the series in Japanese (such as エスカフローネ).

If you want to support the production company in question, then buy an artbook that contains the published *settei*.

Comment: Will this be more Japan-centric version of mecha? I was looking to gather all kinds of culturally affected designs. For deeper research, other parts of the world culture and innovations, what else can you put yojr finger on?

Comment: 「設定資料」is simply the Japanese word for "materials," so any series' materials (originating in any country) that have been made in or sold in Japan could come up in a web search using that phrase plus the name of the series you're looking for. If you search for "settei" in romaji, you will primarily only come across ones from anime. This is the Anime and Manga Stack Exchange, so a search for mech designs that are not from anime/manga would be off-topic here.